# Adj. for doing something to someone in a way they won’t know it’s me

Tags: adjectives

Please fill in the blank with as many words as you can think of:

I’M GOING TO GET REVENGE ON HIM IN A very  _____ WAY (I’ll get revenge but they’ll never know it was because of what they did to me & they’ll never know it was me that got revenge)

A word that almost means hidden, sneaky, sly, etc.

Comment: And that word is, probably, “covert.”

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight that no one will know you did it, you want to do it in a very ***anonymous*** way.  Per the Oxford Living Dictionaries:

> ***[anonymous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anonymous)***
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> 1. (of a person) not identified by name; of unknown name.
>
>    *‘the donor's wish to remain anonymous’*
>    *‘an anonymous phone call’*

So, in your sentence, it would be:

> I'm going to get revenge on him in a very ***anonymous*** way.

I will note, however, that revenge is a bad idea and if law enforcement gets involved, you won't remain anonymous for long.